# PowerShell Windows Froms: consistent GUI

Tags: powershell, windows-forms-designer

Is there a way to make "prefabs" (like in unity) but with PowerShell in Windows Forms? I am currently developing a big “main-script” that will contain several “sub-scripts” for my company. The thing is, I always want to be able to edit the GUI with the editor in Visual Studio (and do not have to edit the code). My only solution that would work right now, is that I would script a separate PowerShell Script that would change the properties (e.g.: the font) of the objects according to there “tag”. The tag property I would set to determine what kind of object it is (title 1, title 2, text 1, …). When I want to edit the GUI, I just need to past the code in the designer and it would work fine.

Comment: I use WPF for these kind of things because of the extensive templating possibilities. Two way databinding through XAML is also possible with Powershell if you use this.

Comment: @bluuf, thank you for responding to my question. I already knew WPF a little bit before. Now I read more about WPF in the "internet". If I understand that correct, there is no possibility to do it directly in the GUI-editor. So, we need to alter the code to make it possible, but that’s not what I want, because I want to see the GUI as it would be displayed when the application is executed. Is there any way to do it only with PowerShell?